Enterprise Territory Management
Within my region (Region A), there are multiple countries (B) and numerous cities (C) within each country.
I'm seeking a method to establish a region as a territory with sub-territories for countries, and further subdivisions for cities under each country. Is there a means to execute an assignment rule within the region, ensuring that accounts in countries and cities are automatically assigned to their respective sections?
To elaborate, is it possible to implement a single assignment rule within my region, using specific criteria, so that all associated countries and cities are assigned accordingly under this region?

A single rule can assign to multiple territories, but there may be size limits in the criteria formula that force you to use multiple rules anyway.  You'll have to try it and fine out.
